# Cannot include my .bib content into my .tex document

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to include my references using PDFLATEX into my document like this :

```
\begin{document}

...
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

But the `cite` command returns empty and the references are not displayed.
What package should i include knowing that i only included `natbib`. Also i put my References.bib in the same folder than my .tex and it starts like this :

```
@article{ref1,
  title={...
```

AND neither can i use `filecontents` :

```
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{jobname}

\end{document}
```

PS : i use TexWorks under Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure to complete your examples such that they contain a suitable document class. Did you remember to run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`? And you'd probably want to use `\jobname` not `jobname`, though that also works.

Comment: Bibtex is returning the error : found no \citation commands---while reading file .aux

Comment: @JohnCampbell Your code is incomplete. Post the entire code.

Comment: You need to run BibTeX as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you get "found no \citation commands" you might not be running the full compile sequence of LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX or you might not be running BibTeX on the correct file (it has to be run on the `.aux` file or extension-less name of your main `.tex` file) or your `.tex` file does not contain any cite commands (unlike the example shown in the question).

Comment: @moewe i don't understand i am using TexWorks' pdflatex compiler for my .tex file, but for the error  found no \citation commands---while reading file .aux was after running using Bibtex compiler

Comment: the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 is not helping me.

Comment: pdfLaTeX and BibTeX are two different programs: Basically pdfLaTeX typesets your document, but cannot resolve citations. BibTeX resolves citations and makes them available to LaTeX. So you always need to run pdfLaTeX, BibTeX, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX together (in that order). See the link I posted above.

Comment: i am trying to run Bibtex on my main .tex file  using TexWorks but getting the .aux error i mentioned

Comment: Hmm. If the code in your main `.tex` file looks anything like the pieces of code shown in the question this shouldn't be happening. (Assuming you did run LaTeX before you ran BibTeX.) But it is hard to diagnose the problem without knowing what your document actually looks like. Please run the following example https://gist.github.com/moewew/57eb80c249f25dbc07878cc734575d30 *without change* (the file `xampl.bib` that is called should be available on all machines with BibTeX) in a *new and empty* folder with pdfLaTeX, BibTeX, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX. Report exactly what happens.

Comment: it is working fine in your example

Comment: Good. Then try to boil your non-working example down to a small example document (in the style of what I posted) where the citations do not work. This will take some time (even though you can probably remove almost all body text immediately and lost of code from the preamble as well), but it is really the only way to enable us to help you properly.

Comment: wheres the content of your xampl file .bib ?

Comment: Forget about the contents of that file for a moment. Just use `\cite{article-full}` (or `\citep` or whatever cite command you use) and `\bibliography{xampl}` in your example document. If the error messages are indeed as described above, the contents of your `.bib` file are unlikely to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Run in TeXWorks: pdflatex + biber + pdflatex + pdflatex

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    ]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\nocite{*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: it says ERROR - Cannot find 'jobname.bib'!

Comment: is working here. maybe your installation is corrupted is some way? try to reinstall MikTeX

Comment: thx it works!!!!!!

Comment: Glad to be your help! Happy TeXting